# Не присвоилась репутация за полученное вознаграждение

Tags: поддержка, репутация

[Подключение шрифта и Opera 9.64](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432908/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-opera-9-64)

Отдал 50 очков репутации пользователю, но его репутация изменилась только за то, что я отметил его ответ правильным, а 50 очков не начислились.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Минимальная длительность конкурса – 1 день.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) Это время уже прошло, репутация начислена, можете проверить [в профиле пользователя](http://%20https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/makarovav?tab=reputation):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На конец вчерашнего дня у него было 838, судя по информации в профиле. Ещё 24 получил до вашей награды. Должно было быть 862. После присвоения награды — 912 . Вознаграждение было начислено за 1 минуту до того, как вы ответ приняли. Думаю, вы просто не заметили, что репутация выросла после присвоения вознаграждения.

Comment: Так у него была репутация 912, я начислил 50 и ничего не изменилось, пометил как правильный и стало 927.

Comment: Скорее всего не заметил, хотя пристально следил.

Comment: @Modal, спасибо все начислилось, не волнуйтесь)